# Reports API Client Library for Java

Tags: google-api, google-api-client

I would like to work in Java with this Google Apps Admin SDK.

There is no samples (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/libraries, link not working), download library is not working, found: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/stable/apps/reporting/reports/v1/java, from https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/api-lib/java

Is only available using, building, treating JSON?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The link on the documentation page is not working, but the team is aware of it and working on fixing the links. In the mean time you can find the download URLs here:

For reports API:
https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/admin/reports_v1/java

For directory API:
https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/admin/directory_v1/java